# Javascript: Check if string can be re-created by combining other strings in an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out the best way to check whether a particular string can be created by combining other strings that I have in an array. The other strings can be any length, including one character. Furthermore, the characters in the other strings can be reordered.

So if we were looking for the word "dodge" and our array of strings was `['god','house','d','e','cat','c','r','jump']`, we would have a match, since we could combine the letters in 'god','d', and 'e' to create 'dodge'.

If the array contained "dot" instead of "d", we would not have a match, since we have to use all the characters in each of the words we recombine (we'd have to use 'o' and 't' as well).

I would also like to know which words were used to create the specified word, so if there is a match I want the function to return the array indexes of the words that were recombined to create the specified word. For the "dodge" example above it would return [0,2,3].

Comment: I like this problem from the algorithmic point of view! I'd be pleased to hear if this is some well known problem (looks like a modification of knap-sack problem) and if there exists some non trivial solution to it.

Comment: @julkiewicz: As I pointed out in my answer below, this problem seems to be equivalent to the subset product problem, which is NP-Complete.

Comment: @Elian, I also got O(2^n). I am thinking whether there is any way to get something like (nlogn) or something.  Since it is NP-Complete it will never work on polynomial time, but maybe something that is better than exponential time...

Comment: @Stephen Chung, I don't think you can do much better than O(2^n) for the worst case, the worst case being a scenario where the dictionary contains a lot of overlapping words like `['aaabc', 'aabbc', 'abbcc', 'aabcc', etc]`. I do think you can optimize for common scenario's, for example you can create  graph that represents the partial ordening of the words based on my `subtract()` method, where `a < b` iff you can subtract b from a. Once you have this graph, you can exclude entire branches if a subtraction fails.

Comment: @makeee, I recommend you pick @Elain's answer.

Comment: @Elian, I have been toying with the idean of constructing a series of regex's to see if it works better with full back-tracking support other than home-grown ones.  However, I can't shake off the fact that it is O(2^n) at the pathological case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a solution that has worst case `O(2^n)`, but it will perform quite well in most situations. I started with a function that maps each string to an object that counts all the different letters in the string. Example:

```
map("dodge") --> { "d": 2, "e": 1, "g": 1, "o": 1, size: 5 }
```

As you can see, it also stores the size in the result. This is the implementation:

```
function map(str) {
    var obj = { size: str.length };

    for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {   
        var ch = str.charAt(i);
        obj[ch] = (ch in obj) ? obj[ch]+1 : 1;
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Then I write a function that "subtracts" two mapped objects. For example:

```
subtract(map("ab"), map("a")) --> { "b": 1, size: 1 }
subtract(map("dodge"), map("god")) --> { "d": 1, "e": 1, size: 1 }
subtract(map("abc"), map("abc")) --> { size: 0 }
subtract(map("a"), map("b")) --> null
```

As you can see in the last example, the function returns `null` if subtraction is not possible. This is an implementation for `subtract`:

```
function subtract(a, b) {
    var result = { size: 0 };

    for(var i=97; i<123; i++) { // from a to z (ASCII)
        var ch = String.fromCharCode(i);
        var diff = (a[ch] || 0) - (b[ch] || 0);

        if(diff < 0)
            return null;

        if(diff > 0) {
            result[ch] = diff;
            result.size += diff;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The last step is writing a method `findCombination(word, dict)` that returns a combination if it finds any, or else null. Examples:

```
var dict = ['god','house','d','e','cat','c','r','jump'];
findCombination("dodge", dict) --> [0, 2, 3]
findCombination("housecat", dict) --> [1, 4]
findCombination("hose", dict) --> null
findCombination("xyz", dict) --> null
```

I use a recursive method with backtracking where I try to "subtract" words from the given key until the result is "empty":

```
var findCombination = function(word, dict)
{
    var solution = [];
    var mappedDict = [];

    for(var i=0; i<dict.length; i++)
        mappedDict[i] = map(dict[i]);           

    var recursiveFind = function(key,  i)
    {
        if(i == mappedDict.length)
            return false;

        var result = subtract(key, mappedDict[i])

        if(result == null)
            return recursiveFind(key, i+1);

        solution.push(i);

        if(result.size == 0 || recursiveFind(result, i+1))
            return true;

        solution.pop();
        return recursiveFind(key, i+1);
    };

    if(recursiveFind(map(word), 0))
        return solution;

    return null;
};
```

You could (and should) optimize the code by initializing the `mappedDict` variable only once, instead of every time `findCombination()` is invoked.

Comment: the subtracting idea is better than mine! It allows for early pruning of the search tree! Mine did a lot more comparisons!

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm:

1. Break the target string into letters and group them, get count of each letter
2. Form all permutations of strings in the array, starting with 1 string and up to the entire array.  If your string array is short (i.e. <32), you can have an auto-increment integer with bitmask to generate all the permutations.  If your string array is long (>32), then use an array to store each "bit" slot with string length, and simulate incrementing integer.
3. Skip all permutations not of the same length as target string (this should eliminate 90% of all permutations).  Get the total letter count by summing the number of "1" bits x length of string (or summing slots); it must = target string length.
4. For each permutation, breakdown down the letters and group them, get count of each letter
5. Run through the target string group letter by letter, compare count to the group of the string. The letters and counts must be exactly the same to succeed.  If so, return that permutation as the answer.
6. Otherwise continue with another permutation
7. After going through all permutations, return fail.

A JavaScript implementation:

```
// Assume: target=target string, words_array=array of strings

function groupByLetters(map, text) {
    for (var x=0; x < text.length; x++) {
        var ch = text.charAt(x);
        var n = map[ch] || 0;
        map[ch] = n + 1;
    }
}

// Split the target string into letters

var target_map = {};
groupByLetters(target_map, target);

// Create permutation slots

var slots = [];

for (var x=0; x < words_array.length; x++) {
    // Now in order to optimize speed, store the length of each string in the slot
    // Negative = not selected, positive = selected
    slots.push(-words_array[x].length);
}

// Loop through all permutations

while(true) {
    var carry = true;
    var plength = 0;

    for (var x=0; x < slots.length; x++) {
        var slen = slots[x];
        if (carry) {
            if (slen < 0) {     // Bit 0
                carry = false;
                slots[x] = -slen;   // 0->1, no carry
            } else {
                slots[x] = -slen;   // 1->0, continue to carry
            }
        }

        if (slots[x] > 0) plength += slots[x];
    }

    if (carry) {    // We have exhausted the permutations
        return null;
    }

    // Now plength = total number of letters in selected permutation

    if (plength !== target.length) continue;    // Not the same number of letters, skip

    // Build map of all letters in selected permutation

    var pmap = {};
    var permutation = [];

    for (var x=0; x < slots.length; x++) {
        if (slots[x] > 0) {
            groupByLetters(pmap, words_array[x]);
            permutation.push(words_array[x]);
        }
    }

    // Check if the map is the same as the target map

    var match = true;

    for (var letter in target_map) {
        if (!target_map.hasOwnProperty(letter)) continue;
        if (target_map[letter] !== pmap[letter]) {
            match = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (match) return permutation;  // Success!
}
```

Caveat: I have **not** tried running this.  Let me know if I made a typo here or there.

Comment: But this doesn't take into consideration the rule that you have to use all the characters in each word that you combine to match the specified word.

Comment: Sorry.  Didn't see that.  Let me try for an amended answer.

Comment: @makeee, I've amended the answer.  Try the algorithm -- it should do what you want.

Comment: Stephen: I'd love a javascript implementation of this. Starting to get a bit over my head.. but I understand the basic concept of what you describe.

Comment: Stephen: It works! Only problem is that it tends to crash the browser when there are around 10+ words. Any ideas why, or performance improvements that you can think of?

Comment: Stephen: I've fixed performance issues by removing words that don't fit in the target word AND which cannot contain the target word. See my changes here and let me know what you think: http://pastebin.com/aTV3P6KA

Comment: @makeee, it probably didn't crash the browser, just takes a long time to run, so the browser times out and thinks your JavaScript has hang.  Running permutations is an O(2^n) algorithm, so it is probably just the slowest thing you can ever run on a computer.  The only way to get around it is to prune the permutations aggressive using anything you can think of.

Comment: Nevertheless, in an O(2^n) algorithm, regardless of the optimizations you make, you're still going to have a very slow program in pathological cases.  Therefore, you should implement some form of a counter and possibly stop the program after running through (x) number of tries without finding an answer.

Comment: The most important thing in optimizing an O(2^n) algorithm is to reduce the number `n`, which is the number of strings in the array.  Therefore you are absolutely correct in eliminting invalid strings early.

Comment: @makeee, I've checked your optimizations.  Please check your logic: word_sorted.indexOf(target_sorted) is always -1 unless word==target, target_sorted.indexOf(word_sorted) may not match if there are other strings containing characters that interspaced into the target (e.g. target="abbc", words="abc"/"b", you'll eliminate the "abc"). You also didn't go far enough.  You should also eliminate words that are 1) length > target, 2) contains letters that do not exist in the target (just loop through each sorted letter and do an indexOf on the single character

Comment: So, I'll rewrite your filter by (no need to sort the strings): for(var x=0; x<word.length; x++) if (target.indexOf(word.charAt(x)) < 0) skip.  Also if (word.length > target.length) skip.  Or you can build a regex on the sorted word (e.g. "abc" -> /.*a.*b.*c.*/) and test the regex on the sorted target string.  That will be more correct than your indexOf method and will do what you want.

Comment: @makeee, look at @Elian's answer. It works in a similar manner (just up-side down from my approach -- it does subtraction while mine does composition). It is a better algorithm because it allows for early pruning of the search tree (e.g. you can skip a word when it does not contain the letters left, or you can skip it when it contains letters that are not left).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
This should be much faster than the naive solution, because all the work is being done by the built-in indexOf search which is really fast, plus it can quit on the first mismatch.

```
function match(array, word){
    var char_array = word.split(''),
        char, index;
    array = array.join('').split('');
    while(char_array.length > 0){
        char = char_array.shift();
        if ((index = array.indexOf(char)) > -1)
            array.splice(index, 1);
        else
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is the naive solution:

```
function match(array, word){
    var char_array = word.split(''),
        array_elem;
    //loop over array
    for(var i=0, l=array.length; i < l; i++){
        array_elem = array[i].split('');
            //loop over the remaining chars in the word and
            //cross-check with the current array element
        for (var j=0,len =  char_array.length,index; j < len; j++)
            if ((index = array_elem.indexOf(char_array[j])) > -1){
                //char matched, remove it from both arrays
                char_array.splice(j, 1);
                array_elem.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    if(char_array.length < 1) return true
        else return false
}
```

There should be optimizations that can be done to make it faster, if that was an issue.

Comment: Does this take into consideration the rule that you have to use all the characters in each word that you combine to match the specified word?

Comment: Yes, the naive solution does, test it. I ignored it in the better performance one.

Comment: Great! I updated my post to include a requirement that the function return an array of the array indexes of the words that were used, such as [4,8,15], so that I know which words were used to create the specified word.

Comment: Amjad: the naive solution doesn't appear to take that rule into consideration. "cod" returns a match with the array ['god','house','d','e','cat','c','r','jump'].

Answer (score 0):

[**See example here →**](http://jsfiddle.net/HTs9S/2/)

```
var wordInDict = function ( word, dict ) {
    var dict = dict.slice(0), // copy dict to not mutate original
        wl = word.length,
        dl = dict.length,
        i, j, diw,
        wCount = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < wl; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < dl; j++) {
            diw = dict[j].indexOf(word[i]); // is letter of word in dict word
            if (diw > -1) {
                wCount++;

                // remove used character from dictionary
                if (diw == dict[j].length-1) {
                    dict[j] = dict[j].slice(0, diw);
                } else if (diw == 0) {
                    dict[j] = dict[j].slice(1);
                } else {
                    dict[j] = dict[j].slice(0,diw) + 
                              dict[j].slice(diw+1,dict[j].length-1);
                }

                // letter found, so move to next letter in target word
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return wCount == wl;
};

var tW = 'dodge';
var tD = ['god','house','d','e','cat','c','r','jump'];
var tE = ['got','house','d','e','cat','c','r','jump'];
console.log(wordInDict(tW, tD)); // true
console.log(wordInDict(tW, tE)); // false
```

Comment: Hey, tried using your function and the word "cod" is also returning true, which it should not since all letters in combined words need to be used.

Comment: Wow, that's hard because it has to know to use the single 'e' instead of the 'e' from 'house' which comes first in the array...  I don't know if you can guarantee the result even if you sort the array by length.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that this problem is equivalent to [the subset product problem](http://www.wolframalpha.com/entities/famous_math_problems/subset_product_problem/oa/xp/7d/), and therefore NP-Complete.

Let `s(x)` be a size method that it returns an integer for every string by mapping the characters to prime numbers and then returning the product of these prime numbers:

```
a --> 2, b --> 3, c --> 5, d --> 7, e --> 11, etc.
```

Then we get

```
s("abc") = 2 * 3 * 5 = 30 = 5 * 2 * 3 = s("cab")
```

Given a dictionary `A`, we are now looking for a subset `A'⊂ A` such that the product

```
p = ∏ { s(a) : a ∈ A' }
```

equals `s(key)` for a given `key`.

Comment: I'm not sure. First of all there is only a finite number of letters, so what about higher prime numbers? Secondly the length of each string is linear in proportion to it's value, whereas in any positional system it is logarithmic.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions possibly I can think of

1. Sort the given strings using Array.sort() and if sorted array matches then boom strings are anagrams.
2. Wrote a piece of native code

   function permutable(input1,input2) {
   if(typeof input1 === 'string' && typeof input2 === 'string' ) {
   const array_1 = input1.split('')
   const array_2 = input2.split('')
   let count2 = 0;
   let count1 = 0
   let is_permutable = false
   if(array_1.length === array_2.length) {
   for(let j =0;j<array_1.length;j++) {
   count1 = checkrepeatations(array_1[j],array_1)
   if(array_2.includes(array_1[j])) {
   count2 = checkrepeatations(array_1[j],array_2)
   }else {
   return false;
   }

   ```
        if(count1 === count2) {
            is_permutable = true;
        } else {
          is_permutable = false;
        }
      }
      if(is_permutable) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      return false
    }

    }else {
      return false;
    }
   ```

   }

   function checkrepeatations(word,array_1) {
   let count = 0;
   let i =0;
   // array_1[j] = t and t e s t
   while(i<array_1.length) {
   //array_1[i] = t
   if(word === array_1[i]) {
   count++;
   }
   i++
   }
   return count;
   }

P.S Learning to code, so any suggestions on memory/variable management are appreciated.